# Missing table after editing README.rst?

Tags: python, string, github

I changed two tables and added:

```
| ``fb2``  | ``BeautifulSoup`` module            | ``BeautifulSoup`` module                     |
+-----------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

```
| ``fb2``  | ``BeautifulSoup`` module            | ``BeautifulSoup`` module                     |
+-----------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

And these tables are completely gone.
I copied the previous two lines exactly and pasted, replacing the html with fb2.
What is wrong and how is it right?

https://github.com/alekssamos/fulltext/blob/master/README.rst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first if adding the right amount of space would be enough to fix it:

```
+-----------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| ``epub``  | ``exiftool`` CLI tool               |                                              |
+-----------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| ``fb2``  | ``BeautifulSoup`` module            | ``BeautifulSoup`` module                     |
+-----------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| ``html``  | ``BeautifulSoup`` module            | ``BeautifulSoup`` module                     |
+-----------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Note how the column are not aligned.
Add one more space after the `fb2` label:

````
+-----------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| ``fb2``   | ``BeautifulSoup`` module            | ``BeautifulSoup`` module                     |
+-----------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| ``html``  | ``BeautifulSoup`` module            | ``BeautifulSoup`` module                     |
+-----------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------```
````

Comment: No, it does not work. Can you show me the finished working file? So I can copy it. I have poor eyesight, I can't see, I don't understand how many spaces are needed.

Comment: @alex33 The idea is to add just one more space after fb2, in the fb2 case.

Comment: @alex33 I have created https://github.com/alekssamos/fulltext/pull/1: The table is visible in https://github.com/alekssamos/fulltext/blob/52a016edcfcf43dd1221d55ed32748855ef9988e/README.rst

Comment: @alex33 You can see that one space in https://github.com/alekssamos/fulltext/pull/1/files